# Spring MVC 4: binding with many to many

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have an application (Spring MVC 4 + Hibernate/JPA + MySQL + Maven integration example using annotations), integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration.
I am following this example:
http://websystique.com/springmvc/springmvc-hibernate-many-to-many-example-annotation-using-join-table/

the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alarm")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@NamedQueries(value = {})
public abstract class Alarm implements Serializable {

    /* */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3210359168688290412L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "action",
            nullable = false)
    private AlarmAction action;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "level",
            nullable = false)
    private AlarmLevel level;

    @Column(name = "type",
            nullable = false,
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private String type;



    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "alarm_guardian",
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "alarm_id",
                                       nullable = false,
                                       updatable = false) },
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "guardian_id",
                                              nullable = false,
                                              updatable = false) })
    private List<Guardian> guardians = new ArrayList<Guardian>();

    //FIXME
    //@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
                mappedBy = "alarms")
    private List<TimeLapse> timeLapses = new ArrayList<TimeLapse>();

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Long version = new Long(0);

    /**
     * Gets the id.
     *
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the id.
     *
     * @param p_id
     *            the new id
     */
    public void setId(final Long p_id) {
        id = p_id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the action.
     *
     * @return the action
     */
    public AlarmAction getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the action.
     *
     * @param p_action
     *            the new action
     */
    public void setAction(final AlarmAction p_action) {
        action = p_action;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the level.
     *
     * @return the level
     */
    public AlarmLevel getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the level.
     *
     * @param p_level
     *            the new level
     */
    public void setLevel(final AlarmLevel p_level) {
        level = p_level;
    }



    /**
     * Gets the type.
     *
     * @return the type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the type.
     *
     * @param p_type
     *            the new type
     */
    public void setType(final String p_type) {
        type = p_type;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the guardians.
     *
     * @return the guardians
     */
    public List<Guardian> getGuardians() {
        return guardians;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the guardians.
     *
     * @param p_guardians
     *            the new guardians
     */
    public void setGuardians(final List<Guardian> p_guardians) {
        guardians = p_guardians;
    }



    public List<TimeLapse> getTimeLapses() {
        return timeLapses;
    }

    public void setTimeLapses(List<TimeLapse> timeLapses) {
        this.timeLapses = timeLapses;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the version.
     *
     * @return the version
     */
    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the version.
     *
     * @param p_version
     *            the new version
     */
    public void setVersion(final Long p_version) {
        version = p_version;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((action == null) ? 0 : action.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((level == null) ? 0 : level.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((version == null) ? 0 : version.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Alarm other = (Alarm) obj;
        if (action != other.action)
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (level != other.level)
            return false;
        if (type == null) {
            if (other.type != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!type.equals(other.type))
            return false;
        if (version == null) {
            if (other.version != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!version.equals(other.version))
            return false;
        return true;
    }





  /*
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final HashCodeBuilder hcb = new HashCodeBuilder();
        hcb.append(getAction());
        hcb.append(getLevel());
        hcb.append(getType());

        return hcb.toHashCode();
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        ToStringBuilder tsb = new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);

        tsb.append("id", getId());
        tsb.append("action", getAction());
        tsb.append("level", getLevel());
        //tsb.append("guardians", getGuardians());
        tsb.append("type", getType());
        //tsb.append("guardians", getGuardians());
        tsb.append("version", getVersion());

        return tsb.toString();
    }*/


}


@Entity
@Table(name = "guardian")
@NamedQueries(value = { @NamedQuery(name = "Guardian.findByCompany",
                                    query = "select g from Guardian as g where g.company.id = :companyId") })
public class Guardian implements Serializable {

    /* */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4899993206680688744L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name",
            nullable = false,
            length = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname",
            nullable = false,
            length = 50)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "description",
            length = 100)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "phone",
            length = 13)
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "email",length = 50)


    @Pattern(regexp = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$", 
            message = "{general.error.mail}")
    private String email;

    /*@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "alarm_guardian",
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "guardian_id",
                                           nullable = false,
                                           updatable = false) },
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "alarm_id",
                                                  nullable = false,
                                                  updatable = false) })
    private List<Alarm> alarms;*/


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id",
                nullable = false)
    private Company company;


    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Long version = new Long(0);

    /**
     * Gets the id.
     *
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the id.
     *
     * @param p_id
     *            the new id
     */
    public void setId(final Long p_id) {
        id = p_id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name.
     *
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name.
     *
     * @param p_name
     *            the new name
     */
    public void setName(final String p_name) {
        name = p_name;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the surname.
     *
     * @return the surname
     */
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the surname.
     *
     * @param p_surname
     *            the new surname
     */
    public void setSurname(final String p_surname) {
        surname = p_surname;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the description.
     *
     * @return the description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the description.
     *
     * @param p_description
     *            the new description
     */
    public void setDescription(final String p_description) {
        description = p_description;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the phone.
     *
     * @return the phone
     */
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the phone.
     *
     * @param p_phone
     *            the new phone
     */
    public void setPhone(final String p_phone) {
        phone = p_phone;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the email.
     *
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the email.
     *
     * @param p_email
     *            the new email
     */
    public void setEmail(final String p_email) {
        email = p_email;
    }


  /*  public List<Alarm> getAlarms() {
        return alarms;
    }


    public void setAlarms(final List<Alarm> p_alarms) {
        alarms = p_alarms;
    }*/



    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the version.
     *
     * @return the version
     */
    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the version.
     *
     * @param p_version
     *            the new version
     */
    public void setVersion(final Long p_version) {
        version = p_version;
    }


  /*  @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object p_obj) {
        boolean isEquals = false;

        try {
            final Guardian guardian = (Guardian) p_obj;
            final EqualsBuilder eb = new EqualsBuilder();

            eb.append(getName(), guardian.getName());
            eb.append(getSurname(), guardian.getSurname());

            isEquals = eb.isEquals();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            isEquals = false;
        }

        return isEquals;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final HashCodeBuilder hcb = new HashCodeBuilder();

        hcb.append(getName());
        hcb.append(getSurname());

        return hcb.toHashCode();
    }*/



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final ToStringBuilder tsb = new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);

        tsb.append("id", getId());
        tsb.append("name", getName());
        tsb.append("surname", getSurname());
        tsb.append("description", getDescription());
        tsb.append("phone", getPhone());
        tsb.append("email", getEmail());
        // tsb.append("alarms", getAlarms());
        tsb.append("version", getVersion());

        return tsb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((company == null) ? 0 : company.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((phone == null) ? 0 : phone.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((surname == null) ? 0 : surname.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((version == null) ? 0 : version.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Guardian other = (Guardian) obj;
        if (company == null) {
            if (other.company != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!company.equals(other.company))
            return false;
        if (description == null) {
            if (other.description != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!description.equals(other.description))
            return false;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (phone == null) {
            if (other.phone != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!phone.equals(other.phone))
            return false;
        if (surname == null) {
            if (other.surname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!surname.equals(other.surname))
            return false;
        if (version == null) {
            if (other.version != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!version.equals(other.version))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

the converter

```
@Component
public class GuardianToAlarmConverver implements Converter<Object, Alarm> {

    @Autowired
    AlarmAccessorService alarmAccessorService;

    @Override
    public Alarm convert(Object element) {
         Long id = Long.parseLong((String)element);
         Alarm alarm = alarmAccessorService.findById(id);

         return alarm;
    }

}
```

my config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.tdk.oti.controller",
                                "com.tdk.oti.converters",
                                "com.tdk.oti.views",
                                "com.tdk.oti.exceptionHandlers"})
public abstract class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    GuardianToAlarmConverver guardianToAlarmConverver;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#addResourceHandlers(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry)
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#configureDefaultServletHandling(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer)
     */
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(final DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#addInterceptors(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry)
     */
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("locale");

        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

        return localeResolver;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#addViewControllers(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry)
     */
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        final TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-layouts.xml", "WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-views.xml" });
        configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);

        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        final TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanNameViewResolver beanNameViewResolver() {
        final BeanNameViewResolver resolver = new BeanNameViewResolver();

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasename("classpath:com/ideefe/iot/i18n/messages");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        return resource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(guardianToAlarmConverver);
    }

    @Bean(name = "gsonMessageConverter")
    public GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonMessageConverter() {
        // @formatter:off
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                            .setPrettyPrinting()
                            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                            .create();
        // @formatter:on

        GsonHttpMessageConverter converter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setGson(gson);

        return converter;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#configureMessageConverters(java.util.List)
     */
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> p_converters) {
        p_converters.add(gsonMessageConverter());
    }

}
```

the JSP

```
<div class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1-1 pure-u-xl-14-24 pure-u-med-1"> 

        <!-- Content Left Wrap -->
        <div id="devices" class="content_l_wrap">
            <div class="windowHead">
                <h2>
                    <spring:message code="alarm.edit.form.title" text="alarm.edit.form.title" />
                </h2>

            </div>
            <div class="windowContent">
                <div class="sigfox_content" data-mcs-theme="dark-3">

                <form:form  id="alarmRegisterForm" 
                            cssClass="form-horizontal" 
                            modelAttribute="alarm" 
                            method="post" 
                            action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/alarm/save" >

                    <form:hidden path="id" value="${alarm.id}"/>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="control-label col-xs-3"><form:label path="action" >Application</form:label> </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <form:select path="application" items="${applications}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="description"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>    

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="control-label col-xs-3"><form:label path="action" >Action</form:label> </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <form:select path="action">
                                <form:options items="${alarmActions}" />
                            </form:select>
                        </div>
                    </div>     

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="control-label col-xs-3"><form:label path="level" >Level</form:label> </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <form:select path="level">
                                <form:options items="${alarmLevels}" />
                            </form:select>
                        </div>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="control-label col-xs-3"><form:label path="level" >Time Lapse</form:label> </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <form:select path="timeLapses" items="${timeLapses}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"    />
                        </div>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="control-label col-xs-3"><form:label path="level" >Guardians</form:label> </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <form:select path="guardians" items="${guardians}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>        

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <input type="button" id="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <input type="submit" id="saveAlarm" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form:form>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

the controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/add" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String addAlarm (final ModelMap model) {

            String userName = getAuthenticationFacade().getAuthenticatedUsername();

            ApplicationAlarm  applicationAlarm = new  ApplicationAlarm();
            model.addAttribute("alarm", applicationAlarm);
            model.addAttribute("alarmActions", AlarmAction.values());
            model.addAttribute("alarmLevels",  AlarmLevel.values());

            List<TimeLapse> timeLapses = getTimeLapseAccessorService().findCompanyTimeLapses(userName);
            model.addAttribute("timeLapses", timeLapses);

            List<Guardian> guardians = getGuardianAccessorService().findCompanyGuardians(userName);
            model.addAttribute("guardians", guardians);

            List<Application> applications = getApplicationAccessorService().findUserApplications(userName);
            model.addAttribute("applications", applications);

            return "alarm.form";
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = { "/save" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAlarm(/* @Valid */ final ApplicationAlarm alarm, final BindingResult result, final ModelMap model) {

        LOGGER.info("Saving the Alarm : " + alarm);

        if(alarm.getId() == null){
            getAlarmMutatorService().save   (alarm);
         } else {
             getAlarmMutatorService().update(alarm);
         }

         return "alarm.list";
     }
```

but the list of guardians is null in the controller

Comment: And where is your controller?

Comment: I would say there is too much code here and too little explanation of a problem. "It doesn't work" means you need to make a shorter, simpler example and get that working first.

Comment: Why do you have to different type columns with the same "mappedBy" ? Are you sure Guardians should be mapped by "alarms"?

Comment: yes, Guardians have alarms and TimeLapses have also alarms